# Brokaw bandgap reference unexpected real world circuit results

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-reference

I have simulated a Brokaw bandgap reference using NPN 2N2222A transistors with a ratio of 4:1, a TL081 opamp and a collector current of about 5 micro-ampere. The simulation  circuit is below with accurate resistor values. When I build this circuit, it does not act as it should. I double-checked my soldering is correct.

[image: This is the design I am following and, according to the document this is in, a similar result to what I should be getting. When I measureme at Vbe, it is about 0.15V. I think this graph is wrong though.]

The circuit output adjusts between 1.60V and 21.4V as is adjusted between 0 and 4.7kOhm with a zero gain resistance ratio. As soon as there is a non-zero gain the output is 22V.

Can anyone with experience building one of these circuits explain why it does not work as expected? Is this the usual case or am I using wrong components potentially?

Update:

I followed some advice and redesigned the circuit with emitter resistors. The worked out to be quite large. The design simulation is in the image below:

[image]

The circuit works in simulation but not as well as a Zener diode with respect to change in both source and temperature.

Comment: How does the design handle discrete part variation? If anything, this looks like it was made for IC design. I need to think more about this particular design, though. In the past, I recall having to operate the BJTs at different current densities (which I think I see with Q1 there.) But I need to see how this is added up properly. Temperature stability is everything here. Did you do any calcs that included part variation? Or just depend upon simulation which simulates every single part exactly the same way? In the real world, for example (not IC worlds), you can't tie BJT pins like that.

Comment: Sidebar: There is a book called "Current Sources and Voltage References: A Design Reference for Electronics Engineers," which you might consider. My copy is due to arrive tomorrow, I think.

Comment: Thank you so much @jonk. This subject is very new to me. I really wish my course covered some of this. I will try to get a copy of that book and read up some more on it.

Comment: If you wire up bjts like that, all pins tied, they do not share currents. One of them pretty much takes over and the rest just mess things up. One trick is often used where a small emitter resistor is added, one per emitter, to help balance things. The IC folks get to cheat, because the can just add emitters and they are guaranteed to be thermally bound, besides.

Comment: @jonk Thank you for that bit of advice. I put 1 Ohm resistors at the emitters of the 4 bound together transistors. It simulates well and helped a bit but it is still does not function right. The op amp does get quite I have found.

Comment: Well, the resistors need to drop about \$300mV\$ or so. Not sure if \$1\Omega\$ would do that. Sorry about forgetting to mention that detail.

Comment: @jonk I understand now how the emitter resistors work. If I want to design the value of the resistors would I design for 300mV across them with Ie flowing through them? Would that then for part of the Vbe for the rest of the design?

Comment: Yes. But for other times where you want to encourage the BJTs, with realistic variations in parameters, to equitably share their current densities. For some uses that's fine. But it doesn't cause the densities to be the same -- just a lot nearer. How this impacts a bandgap reference is another matter I haven't yet considered well. I'm going to spend time on the idea later on, because I'm personally interested if it is even possible to fabricate (and calibrate) a bandgap reference from discrete parts. (It's easy for IC folks. But I don't know if anyone has done it -- lately anyway -- discrete.)

Comment: @jonk I redesigned with emitter resistors. it simulates well but a simple Zener diode has better performance.

Comment: I'm not surprised. If they were supposed to be there (and they aren't, when you are using a FAB IC based circuit design) they would include them. They actually ruin the design. But if you are building this out of discrete parts, you have little option. The whole idea is like using a jet engine for a street car. Completely mismatched designs.